# Android ListView: detecting if first/last row is visible after scroll is finished

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-listview

I have to implement a sort of pagination for a subclass of `ListView`. 
When the user scrolls down the list, the scroll is finished and he views the last row, I have to request next page of data, if any. Same thing for scroll up/first row/previous page.

```
public class ContactList extends ListView implements OnGestureListener {

    GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public ContactList(Context context) {
        super(context);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
    }

//Other ctors here...       
}
```

I then attached a GestureDetector to the ListView, forwarding to it all the touches.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Can I detect in my `OnGestureListener.onScroll()` if first/last row is visible using `getFirst/LastVisiblePosition()`?

Maybe this method is called *before* the scroll occurs?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to setup [`OnScrollListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) for your ListView and gather positions from `onScroll` callback:

```
    setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // You cat determine first and last visible items here
            // final int lastVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount - 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Comment: Shame on me! When I googled around I searched for "android scroll listener", and I found no OnScrollListener stuff :( Let me the time to study it. Many thanks! :)